# How to dynamically enable the textbox?

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have 10 textbox and corresponding to that I have 10 dropdown boxes .
So my requirement is when I fill the text in first textbox and select its corresponding dropdown list , then only second textbox and its corresponding dropdown should be activate else they all should be deactivate.

How do I achieve it using angular 2+ ??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the `*.ts`-file do something like:

```
value: string;

isValueEmpty(): boolean {
  if ('' !== this.value && this.value.length > 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

In the `*.html`-file do something like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" />
<mat-select *ngIf="isValueEmpty()">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

You probably want to iterate those fields:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  ...
</div>
```

Then you need to change your function accordingly.

`*.html`-file:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" />
<mat-select *ngIf="isValueEmpty(value)">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

`*.ts`-file:

```
isValueEmpty(value: string): boolean {
  if ('' !== value && value.length > 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.